# DialogFlow BOT no responde a las preguntas correctamente

Tags: dialogflow

me he iniciado hace poco en el mundo de DialogFlow, he creado un par de intents pero cuando por ejemplo le pregunto a bot algo me responde con algo diferente a lo que yo quiero que me responda.

Si alguien supiese si tengo que configurar algun parametro o algo para hacer que me responda coherentemente, es que en la pregunta intento poner la misma palabra que en la respuesta pero aun así no me responde correctamente.

Adjunto una captura para que lo entendais:

[image: No responde la pregunta correctamente]

Gracias por la ayuda.

Un saludo.

Answer (score 0):

En tus respuestas tienes 7, posibles respuestas a tu pregunta.
Cuando haces la pregunta, e ingresa a la intención te va responder aleatoriamente con cualquiera de ellas.
Solo debería estar la respuesta 6 para ese Intent.
Supongo que las otras respuestas son para otras preguntas.
Deberías tener 7 Intens según tu ejemplo.